# How to return boolean true if dictionary contains a value else false

Tags: c#

[image]How to return true if the dictionary contains key 1 else return false. how can change below line to return boolean

var dicResult = dic.Where(p => p.Key == 1);

Comment: The alternatives in the answers are better, but if you strictly want to 'change your line to return a boolean' you can add a comparer, in this case `>`, which gives `var dicResult = dic.Where(p => p.Key == 1) > 0;`

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: You can't use `> 0` with `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Darn, looks like my `.Count()` did not copy. Indeed, can't compare to 0 in that form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of `Where`. It returns true if the condition is matched

```
bool result = dic.Any(p => p.Key == 1);
```

the same in VB.NET is

```
Dim result = dic.Any(Function(p) p.Key = 1)
```

**EDIT**
In response to the comment below, you could use the same pattern for checking dates stored as strings in the Value of your dictionary

```
Dim dic = New Dictionary(Of Int32, String)()
dic.Add(1, "14/07/2015")
Dim result = dic.Any(Function(x) DateTime.Parse(x.Value) > DateTime.Parse("11/07/2015"))
Console.WriteLine(result)
```

(My locale is dd/MM/yyyy)

Comment: I would be looking for C#. This should be fine.

Comment: It's tagged only C#, so it's probably not VB.NET.

Comment: Initially there was a VB.NET tag, leaving the VB.NET version for completeness.

Comment: How about using for this datetime values in same context

Comment: Dim result As Boolean = dictionary.Any(Function(r) DateTime.Parse(r.Value) > DateTime.Parse(str))

Comment: Well should work, it is boolean expression. But Parse is a bit risky if you are not 100% sure about the format of your strings. And probably the second Parse should be done outside the expression

Comment: This doesnt work , near r.Value value is not being retrieved
                                    Dim result As Boolean = dictionary.Any(Function(r) DateTime.Parse(r.Value) > DateTime.Parse(str))

Comment: Strange it works for me. Adding an example to the answer

Comment: I am getting false even if the newly passed date is greater than one in dictionary

Comment: please check attached picture

Comment: And what is the value of str? I am a bit confused now. This is going on another direction from the original question. (and switching back to VB.NET) Perhaps it is better to post a new question.

Comment: @Steve posted up here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417838/how-to-check-if-a-value-in-a-dictionary-is-greater-than-value-being-passed

Answer (score 5):

You can use `dict.ContainsKey(key)`. This will return true if it contains that key.

Assuming your dictionary is defined something like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dict.Add(1, "Hello");
Console.WriteLine(dict.ContainsKey(1)); // True
Console.WriteLine(dict.ContainsKey(3)); // False
```