# How to check if a value in a dictionary is greater than value being passed

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim dictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, String) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)


 dictionary.Add(i, str)

 Dim rs = dictionary.Where(Function(r) DateTime.Parse(r.Value) > DateTime.Parse(str))
```

I am dynamically adding some values to the dictionary where Key is of integer type and value is of string type.

So After adding to dictionary I need to check in where condition whether newly passed value is greater than all values inside dictionary. If yes it should return Boolean true value else false

Comment: You should add some examples of the values that you store in the dictionary and what is the value of str. Perhaps we could find why the actual code doesn't work

Comment: Why are you storing the values as String if they represent a DateTime?

Answer (score 1):

The following code does what you ask.

```
Dim dictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, String) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
dictionary.Add(0, "1-May-2015")
dictionary.Add(1, "6/10/15")

Dim i As Integer = 2
Dim str As String = "2015-06-11"
Dim larger As Boolean = dictionary.All(Function(r) DateTime.Parse(r.Value) < DateTime.Parse(str))
dictionary.Add(i, str)

MessageBox.Show(str & " is " & If(larger, "", "not") & " larger than all previous values")
```

The check is done before adding the new item to the dictionary so that the Boolean value is False if the the new date is equal to the largest previous date.

However, you should probably be storing your dates as DateTime instead of String in a Dictionary(Of Integer, DateTime).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A dictionary uses a complex hashing function to hash the key and return the value. Hence, a dictionary does not care about the value.

However, there is a simple solution to your problem.
All you need to do is to store a variable which holds the greatest number. If the new number is the greatest then update this variable and return true.